# how to grep 2 words in mid of the string

Tags: regex, grep

```
string1=ram is going to school

string2=ram is playing the match
```

i know we can grep like below -

```
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep 'going'| grep 'school' | wc -l`
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep 'playing'| grep 'match' | wc -l`
```

but i want to use only 1 grep, i have tried many ways but not getting the excepted o/p -

```
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep '*going*school' | wc -l`
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep -e '*going*school' | wc -l`
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep '\*going\*school' | wc -l`
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep -G '*going\*school' | wc -l`
isTrue=`echo $string1 |egrep '*going*school' | wc -l`
```

is there any way to do it using 1 grep?

Comment: Use `grep -q 'going .* school'`

Comment: Your first 2 examples would return `0` always

Comment: Still, this is not working

Answer (score 0):

i am able to get the expected answer -

```
isTrue=`echo $string1 |grep '.*going.*school' | wc -l`
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: That's wrong in several ways. Learn how to use quotes, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Learn how to use command substitution, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082. Copy/paste this and any other shell script you write into http://shellcheck.net until you grasp the fundamentals. Think about what `.*` matches at the start of your regexp (hint - anything or nothing) and what would change about the matching strings if you removed it (hint - nothing).  Also look at `-c` in the grep man page as you don't need to pipe the output to `wc -l`.

Comment: Also, `isTrue` sounds like a boolean so setting it to a count of matching lines isn't obviously correct vs using `grep -q 'going .* school'` as @anubhava suggested in [the very first comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078614/how-to-grep-2-words-in-mid-of-the-string#comment122088681_69078614) and then setting isTrue based on it's exit status.